# Do I need to declare relation type for both models in Loopback?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

Say, I have `Order` and `Customer` models.

`Customer` `hasMany` `Order`.

`Order` `belongsTo` `Customer`.

Do I need to set both relations in Customer and in Order models or is only one necessary? How will it affect the way I save and query data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set both in order to get Loopback to generate the API calls for these relations.
So, let's say that you only set the Customer hasMany Order, only the
methods described [here](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasMany-relations.html) will be added. (Also, the respective API endpoints are added).
If you set it he other way, you'll get these described in [here](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/BelongsTo-relations.html).

- BTW, only one change occurs in the DB, and it's a customerId field in the
  Order table.